# Игнорирование только букв в регулярных выражениях

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть регулярное выражение:

```
std::regex rx{ R"((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](\d\d)\d\d)" };
```

И есть такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>  //для ввода/вывода при работе с файлами
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

string check_filename(string filename)
{
ifstream file;
file.open(filename);
while (!file.is_open())
{
    cout << "Input the correct filename>";
    getline(cin, filename);
    file.open(filename);
}
return filename;
}

string vec_to_str(vector<string> b, string a)
{
a.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < b.size() - 1; ++i)
{
    a += b[i] + ' ';

}
a += b[b.size() - 1];
return a;
}

void file_to_str(string& a,string filename)
{
ifstream file;
file.open(filename);
char c;
while ((c = file.get()) != -1)
{
    a.push_back(c);
}
}

void ch_to_vec(vector<string>& b, string a)
{
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i)
{
    if (isspace(a[i]) && !b.back().empty())
        b.push_back({});
    else
        b.back() += a[i];
}
}

bool check_wish(bool wish)
{

string no;//переменная,отвечающая за продолжение
do
{
    if (no == "y" || no == "yes")
    {
        wish = true;
    }

    cout << "Continue? (Y/N)>";

    while (!(cin >> no) || (cin.peek() != '\n')) //цикл,отвечающий за проверку вводимых типов данных
    {
        cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        std::cout << "Continue? (Y/N) > ";

    }

    transform(no.begin(), no.end(), no.begin(), ::tolower); // понимжение регистра

} while (no != "n" && no != "no" && no != "y" && no != "yes");

if (no == "n" || no == "no")
{
    wish = false;
}
return wish;
}

void seraching_for_match(vector<string> b, int &count, regex rx, vector<string> date)
{
for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
{
    if (regex_match(b[i], rx) == true)
    {
        date.push_back(b[i]);
        count = 1;
    }
}
}

void seraching_for_min(vector<string> date)
{
string min = date[0];
for (int i = 1; i < date.size(); ++i)
{
    if (date[i] < min)
    {
        min = date[i];
    }
}
cout << "Earliest date >" << min << endl;
}

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
//ifstream - файловый ввод ;ofstream - файловый вывод
ifstream file;     //объект file класса ifstream - отвечает за входной файл

bool wish = true;

regex rx{ R"((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[012])[.](\d\d)\d\d)" };

cout << "Earliest date\n";

while (wish)
{
    cout << "Input a filename>";

    string filename;

    getline(cin, filename);

    vector<string> b(1);
    string a;                       //строка a - в нее будет записывать строка из файла,а затем и     обновленная строк,если таковая будет
    vector <string> date;

    file.open(filename);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        filename = check_filename(filename);
        file.open(filename);
    }

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        

        file_to_str(a, filename);

        ch_to_vec(b, a);

        int count = 0; //есть ли дата или нет

        

        for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
        {
            /*if (regex_match(b[i], rx) == true)
            {
                date.push_back(b[i]);
                count = 1;
            }*/
            for (std::sregex_token_iterator ib{ b[i].begin(), b[i].end(), rx }, ie; ib != ie; ++ib)
            {
                date.push_back(*ib);
                count = 1;
                std::cout << *ib << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            seraching_for_min(date);
        }

        if (count == 0)
        {
            cout << "There are no dates in format \"DD.MM.YYYY\" " << endl;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    //file1 << a;
    //file1.close();

    wish = check_wish(wish);
    cin.ignore();
}
return 0;
}
```

од должен искать в строке выражение типа дд.мм.гггг
Как можно настроить код выше,чтобы игнорировались только буквы ?(Например,*Текст*дд.мм.гггг*Текст*,или *Текст*дд.мм.гггг, или дд.мм.гггг*Текст*, а выводится только дд.мм.гггг)
Он это делает, но проблема в том, что если за дд.мм.гггг стоят цифры:
12.12.20023, то он выведет ту часть,которая соответствует шаблону дд.мм.гггг - 12.12.2002, хотя он должен это игнорировать. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте дополнить regexp негативными просмотрами  назад `(?<!\d)` и вперед `(?!\d)`. Т.е.: `(?<!\d)(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[.](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[.](19|2[01])\d{2}(?!\d)` вот таким образом с обоих сторон отделить

Comment: @PotroNik `std::regex` не поддерживает просмотров назад.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо за замечание, как раз смотрел по этому поводу документации. Правильно понимаю, что тогда не остается других вариантов, как делать группа без захвата, на все кроме цифры или начало строки `(?:[^\d]|^)`?

Comment: Да, нужна подмаска, а её тип зависит от конкретной задачи.